# List as global variable inside a class in Python

Tags: python, variables, global

I get this error when I set the list numbers as a global variable inside a class. Here is my code:

```
class SomeClass:

  numbers = [4, 6, 8, 2, 10] 

  def incrementNumbers(self):
    global numbers   

    for i in numbers:
      i += 1
      print (i)

someObject = SomeClass()

someObject.incrementNumbers()
```

When I run the code i get the error "name 'numbers' is not defined". If I declared 'numbers' as global, why is considered not defined?

Comment: You defined `numbers` as a class variable, not as a global variable. A global variable must be defined outside of any class or function.

Comment: That is not a global variable that is a class variable, only accesible through the class namespace

Comment: this error means there is no way you have a ```numbers``` list outside your class. If you need to use the list inside your class then there is no need to write ```global numbers```, remove it @VladETC

Comment: @HozayfaElRifai Simply removing `global` is not enough. See my answer.

Comment: @DYZ yeah, I forgot about that... thanks

Comment: @Vlad, If any of the answers helped you, you should choose one as solution and upvote as many of the answers as you consider appropriate. If none helped, then it would be nice if you comment and tell us, so that we can adapt / improve our answers.

Answer (score 4):

To fix the scope problem, either declare the variable outside of the class (make it truly global) or access it as a class variable, as shown below. Incidentally, your code *does not* increment the list items. If you want to increment the list items, refer to them by index, not by value:

```
class SomeClass:
  numbers = [4, 6, 8, 2, 10] 

  def incrementNumbers(self):
    for i in range(len(SomeClass.numbers)):
      SomeClass.numbers[i] += 1
    print(SomeClass.numbers)
```

Comment: Nitpick, the list items aren't copied, it is the items in the list, but neither those objects nor the list is mutated

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - Do you mean the original solution or my solution?

Comment: In the original solution. Your solution mutates the list

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That's my interpretation of the OPs goal: to mutate the list.

Comment: Yes I know, but I'm saying that it's never the case that accessing the elements in a list gives you a copy of those objects which your answer implies by "It increments their copies". No copies are made here

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Oh, I see, and I disagree. At each iteration, the original loop variable `i` _is_ a copy of the next list item, and it is incremented, but the incremented value is overwritten at the next iteration.

Comment: That is definitely incorrect. I don't know where you got that impression, but you can disabuse yourself of that by using `id`, or use a mutable object and mutate it. Accessing an object **never** creates a copy. Of course, you could implement a container type that does this, but none of the built-in containers do this

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you for the clarification. As it turns out, it is the statement `i+=1` that creates a new object: `id(i)` before the increment and after the increment is different. Cool.

Comment: ```SomeClass.numbers = [i + 1 for i in SomeClass.numbers]``` is more pythonic

Comment: @ Hozayfa El Rifai Yes it might be more pythonic, but it is not 100% identical, as it creates a new object for `SomeClass.numbers` , which might be an issue depending on how the class variable is used. (e.g. in a htreading application, in an application, where somebody keeps a reference to `SomeClass.numbers` So perhaps:
`SomeClass.numbers[:] = [i + 1 for i in SomeClass.numbers]` ?

Comment: minor comment about the answer:
If inheritance is involved and somebody overloads the clas variable, then `SomeClass.numbers` will nob behave identical to `self.__class__.numbers`

The first one is nicer to read, though prone to errors if the class is ever renamed and probably not doing what one expects if in inherited class overwrote `numbers`

Answer (score 1):

The variable `numbers`, that you declare is not a global variable, it is a class variable.

If you want a global variable, then you had to write:

```
numbers = [4, 6, 8, 2, 10] 

class SomeClass:

  def incrementNumbers(self):
    # next line would be only needed if numbers were a 
    # simple type (like for example an int) and if you wanted 
    # to modify it or if it were any type and you want to be allowed to assign to it (same as modyfing a simple type)  from inside this function. 
    # So for your exact example you can just  leave this line of
    # Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga for pointing this out.

    # global numbers

    for i in numbers:
      i += 1
      print (i)

someObject = SomeClass()

someObject.incrementNumbers()
```

Also if you want, that inc is persistent, then you had to write (as @DYZ mentioned) `numbers[i] += 1` instead of `i += 1`

For a class var `SomeClass.numbers[i] += 1` or `this.__class__.numbers[i] += 1`

But perhaps you didn't mean global var, but a class var.

Then @DYZ's answer could be interesting, though I want to elaborate on it with a slightly more complex example.

It highlights the difference between global vars, class vars, class vars of an object and class vars of a specific class, which might be important if you have class inheritance.

Please note, that as long as the object does not have a `numbers` attribute, then `self.numbers` and `this.__class__.numbers` behave identical for reading, but not for assigning.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

numbers = ["g1", "g2"]

class SomeClass:
  numbers = [4, 6, 8, 2, 10]

  def func_1(self):
    print("              numbers is", numbers)
    print("self          numbers is", self.numbers)
    print("class         numbers is", SomeClass.numbers)
    print("class of self numbers is", self.__class__.numbers)
    print()

class SomeOtherClass:
  numbers = [4, 6, 8, 2, 10]

  def __init__(self):
    self.numbers = ["a", "b", "c"]

  def func_1(self):
    print("              numbers is", numbers)
    print("self          numbers is", self.numbers)
    print("class         numbers is", SomeClass.numbers)
    print("class of self numbers is", self.__class__.numbers)
    print()

class DerivedClass(SomeClass):
    numbers = [1, 2]

class OtherDerivedClass(SomeClass):
    numbers = [3, 4]

    def __init__(self):
        self.numbers = ["o1", "o2", "o3"]


c1 = SomeClass()
c2 = SomeOtherClass()
c3 = DerivedClass()
c4 = OtherDerivedClass()

c1.func_1()
c2.func_1()
c3.func_1()
c4.func_1()
```

The output for above example would be:

```
              numbers is ['g1', 'g2']
self          numbers is [4, 6, 8, 2, 10]
class         numbers is [4, 6, 8, 2, 10]
class of self numbers is [4, 6, 8, 2, 10]

              numbers is ['g1', 'g2']
self          numbers is ['a', 'b', 'c']
class         numbers is [4, 6, 8, 2, 10]
class of self numbers is [4, 6, 8, 2, 10]

              numbers is ['g1', 'g2']
self          numbers is [1, 2]
class         numbers is [4, 6, 8, 2, 10]
class of self numbers is [1, 2]

              numbers is ['g1', 'g2']
self          numbers is ['o1', 'o2', 'o3']
class         numbers is [4, 6, 8, 2, 10]
class of self numbers is [3, 4]
```

If you need any explanations of why you get expected output, don't hesitate to comment and I'll try to clarify

Comment: No need for `global numbers`

Comment: true. global would only be needed ig numbers were for example an `int` and if you wanted to modify it.

Will adapt my answer.

Comment: No, it doesn't matter the type. If you want to *assign to the global variable* then `global` is required, regardless of type

Comment: Please see my my comment within the answer @juanoa,arrivalage.

Comment: Thank you. This is much more than I expected. And yes, I needed a class variable.

Comment: In that case you might accept DYZ's answer as solution,

Answer (score 1):

To access a property of the same object within a class function you need to use `self`

```py
class SomeClass:

  numbers = [4, 6, 8, 2, 10] 

  def incrementNumbers(self):
    for i in self.numbers:
      i += 1
      print(i)

someObject = SomeClass()

someObject.incrementNumbers()
```

Comment: please note, that `self` works only if you do not want to assign to the class variable and if nobody uses the same name for an object member and a class member.
`self.__class__` (as shown in my answer) will always work